# Not able to implement subgraphs in Mermaid flowchart

Tags: javascript, graph, flowchart, mermaid

I am using the mermaid js library for creating a flowchart.
I have reached this point as of now:

```
graph TD;
    Process_1---Subprocess_11;

    Process_2---Subprocess_21;
    Subprocess_21---Subprocess_22;
    Subprocess_22---Subprocess_23;
```

which looks like this
[image: Mermaid Flowchart]

As seen, I need subgraphs for my representation. And I read on [this](https://knsv.github.io/mermaid/#subgraphs) webpage about the usage of 'subgraphs'. So I tried the following code:

```
graph TD;
    subgraph one;
    Process_1---Subprocess_11;
    end;

    subgraph two;
    Process_2---Subprocess_21;
    Subprocess_21---Subprocess_22;
    Subprocess_22---Subprocess_23;
    end;
    Process_1-->Process_2;
```

This throws some kind of error like:
[image: error message]

Please help me in knowing what am I doing wrong! Is it some wrong version issue? If so, where can I get the latest stable version? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to get rid of the semicolons? It works fine on my Chrome.
[image]